# Finiteness of $A\times B$ implies finiteness of $A$ and $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Problem*

If $A\times B$ is finite ,does it follow that $A$ and $B$ are finite.

*Attempt*

Consider a function $f\colon A\times B\to A : f(a,b)= a$ and 
$g\colon A\times B\to B: g(a,b)=b$ .
Both are one-to-one and onto.
Hence both are bijective .

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Have you tried to play with your proof? Try it assuming $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$, and see if the functions you have are really bijective.

Comment: Projections are not bijections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case $A$ or $B$ is empty, then so is $A \times B$ in which case the other one need not be finite

Answer (score 3):

$f$ is only onto !  We have $f(A \times B)=A$. Since $A \times B$ is finite, we get that $A$ is finite:

$A \times B= \{x_1,,,,, x_n\}$, then $A=f(A \times B)=\{f(x_1),...,f(x_n)\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if wrong :

Let $A,B \not =\emptyset$.

1) Consider the set

$C:=${$(a,b_1)| a \in A$ , $ b_1 \in B$, fixed}.

$C \subset A×B$, hence finite.

$f: C \rightarrow A$ , $f: (a,b_1) = a$ , is a bijection , hence $A$ is finite.

How about $B$?